# Margin remove in html javascript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to remove the white margins from this web page.

[image: Text]

Code of webpage:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <iframe id="i1" src="yoursource1.html" width="100%" style="height:100vh"></iframe>
  <iframe id="i2" src="yoursource2.html" width="100%" style="height:100vh"></iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframes have a default display type of inline. Inline elements are initially designed for text and your iframe acts a bit as one giant character. It has a bit of white space beneath for the descenders of the characters (characters like j and g have descenders).

To cut a long story short, try changing the display type with css (and remove the border).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="i1" src="yoursource1.html" width="100%" style="height:100vh; background:black"></iframe>
<iframe id="i2" src="yoursource2.html" width="100%" style="height:100vh; background:black"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not worked. At least in firefox.

Comment: also remove the border :)

Comment: Yet not working. More complete code in pastebin https://pastebin.com/9bsD3iPn

Comment: now is working very well